# Some properties about the equation $P(z)\phi(z)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, rational-functions, quantum-computation, quantum-groups

Let $\phi(z)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty (\phi_{m}z^m-\psi_{-m}z^{-m})$ where $\phi_m, \psi_{-m}\in \mathbb{C}$.

If we can find one polynomial $P(z)\in \mathbb{C}[z]$ such that $P(z)\phi(z)=0$, how can I get some properties about $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \phi_{m}z^m$ and $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \psi_{-m}z^{-m}$ from this equation $P(z)\phi(z)=0$?

For example:

$(1):$Can I get that $\phi(z)$ is a rational function?

$(2):$ Can I get $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \phi_{m}z^m=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \psi_{-m}z^{-m}$?

Here, the left hand and the right hand  can be viewed as the same rational function expanding at $0$ and $\infty$?

**Why I have this question**

I am reading a paper  [Asymptotic representations and Drinfeld
rational fractions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/asymptotic-representations-and-drinfeld-rational-fractions/C52DB785A9C6F9DDA093B589F41644C4), the doi of this paper is $10.1112/S0010437X12000267$.

In this paper's lemma 3.9, if we define $\Psi(z)=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Psi_{i,k}z^k$, the author proves that $$\sum_{m=0}^Na_mz^{N-m}\bigg(\Psi_i(z)-\sum_{p=0}^m\Psi_{i,p}z^p\bigg)=0.$$

Then he conclude that $\phi(z)=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi_{i,k}z^k$ is rational.

I want to know if the author means that $\Psi_i(z)= \sum_{p=0}^m\Psi_{i,p}z^p$ is the true rational function?

Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see that in Lemma 3.9 of the paper you linked.  The author shows that $$\sum_{m=0}^N a_m z^{N-m} \left( \Psi_i(z) - \sum_{p=0}^m \Psi_{i,p} z^p \right) = 0$$ and concludes that $\Psi_i(z)$ is rational.  That's certainly true: explicitly $$ \Psi_i(z) = \dfrac{\sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{p=0}^m a_m  \Psi_{i,p} z^{N-m+p}}{\sum_{m=0}^N a_m z^{N-m}}$$

Comment: @Robert Israel  Thank you very much. Maybe I misunderstand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series).  I presume it is supposed to converge to $\phi(z)$, at least in some annulus $A = \{z: r < |z| < R\}$ with $r < R$.

If $P(z) \phi(z) = 0$ where $P$ is a polynomial not identically $0$, then $\phi(z) = 0$ everywhere in $A$.  And then all the coefficients are $0$ by the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: @ Robert Israel  Thanks!  I have edited the question.  I want to know if I am right.